# What is the worst time case for Arduino Mega?

Tags: arduino-mega, relay, hc-05, home-automation

I'm going to implement home automation using an Arduino Mega with 8*6=48 channels relay in my new home. I have prepared an Android app for an HC-05 Bluetooth controller. How much time can I keep running an Arduino Mega with all the appliances in a home? Can I keep it working 24/7 for a while?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Just make sure you get a proper power supply. I'd also suggest using the watchdog timer, so that if the program somehow hangs, it will reset itself. Maybe tie the reset pin of the HC05 to an Arduino pin, so you can reset it. That way you never have to manually reset the system if anything happens. Also, maybe have a certified electrician take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I keep it working 24/7 for a while?

yes, if properly designed.

Comment: Your answer is rather terse. Please expand on it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

(For better guidance than that, we'd need to know more.)

Answer (score 0):

I would be wary of going "all in" if the MCU holds+controls the state of all the relays, especially if there's networking happening in the sketch. That creates a single-point of failure for the whole house. I've found that a brief power outage or an MCU freeze/reboot resets the state. That can be frustrating and downright dangerous in a emergency situation.

An obvious solution is to save the relay states in EEPROM or externally on a server. The issue with those is that EEPROM wears out, and your server might not be available soon after a power-cycle when the MCU needs it to resume (router re-connecting, computer rebooting slower than MCU, etc).

The real solution, and the one that preserves life-safety is having local hardware state for each relay. You need the ability to both read state from the Arduino, and change the state from the Arduino. This can be as simple (yet expensive) as physically latching relays, or a capacitor-backed 1-bit state machine like an RS flip-flop. You can build the flip-flop in a variety of circuits, from shift registers, to a 555, to a simple NPN+n-channel MOSFET coupling (my pref).

The big downside is that this needs two pins for each relay. But, with such "smart relays", you can unplug the Arduino and nothing happens around the house. It also allows non-Arduino things (even a simple button/switch) to control the state of a relay, no matter what's happening with the Arduino at the time, but with the ability of the Arduino to react to that change and not over-write or forget the state. The MCU can reboot on a schedule to keep responsive, without anyone noticing the reboot.

Yes, it adds more complexity and cost, but a manageable amount of both, and the satisfaction difference is hard to truly express. In short, any system should work as reliably as lights did 100 years ago: switches work, and never unexpectedly change. If lights are not working or are turning off unexpectedly in a small fire, things can get ugly quick, especially with guests.